# Calculate the integral $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{(x-a)^2}{\sqrt{(1-x)}\ (1-ax)^4} dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I've come across an integral that I'm not sure how to solve (nor am I sure whether it can be solved). I have tried to analyse the integral by the contour method but I'm not really sure where to begin, can anybody give me any pointers?

Integral:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{(x-a)^2}{\sqrt{(1-x)}\ (1-ax)^4} dx$$

where $0<a<1$ is a constant.

Thanks!

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) can be a good place to start with these kind of questions: we can [use it to find $\displaystyle\int\frac{(x-a)^2}{\sqrt{1-x}(1-ax)^4}\,dx$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+((x-a)%5E2)%2F(root(1-x)(1-ax)%5E4)+dx) - can you continue?

Comment: thanks for the response! yes, I can substitute the limits into this solution to evaluate the integral.

Comment: @lioness99a The fun part is trying to figure out how WolframAlpha got there, or the occasional integral even WA can't solve.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I agree! But it can be very useful if you're not sure what you're aiming for. And sometimes it can give an insight for where to start

Comment: I would set $$t=\sqrt{1-x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{(x-a)^2}{\sqrt{1-x}\ (1-ax)^4} dx
=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{(x-a)^2\sqrt{1-x}}{(1-x)(1-ax)^4} dx\\
=\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\frac{\frac{a}{(a-1)^2}}{ax-1}+
\frac{\frac{a}{a-1}}{(ax-1)^2}+
\frac{\frac{a^2-1}{a}}{(ax-1)^3}
+\frac{\frac{(a+1)^2(a+1)}{a}}{(ax-1)^4}+
\frac{\frac{1}{(a-1)^2}}{1-x}\right)\sqrt{1-x} dx\\
$$
Now solve each one by substitution $t=\sqrt{1-x}$: 
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{(1-ax)^n}dx=
\int\frac{t}{(1-a(1-t^2))^n}\cdot-2tdt=
\int\frac{-2t^2}{(1-a+at^2)^n}dt
$$
it is not easy but possible...

Comment: oh wow! thanks for the help, think I can do it now!